# Is FAQ tab of a tag sorting questions correctly?

Tags: discussion, sorting, frequent-tab

Is the sorting of questions in the FAQ tab of a tag working correctly?

If you look at [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby?sort=faq), the first two questions only have one linked question each ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661062/installing-paperclip-undefined-method-has-attached-file-for-ruby-on-rails) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841406/cannot-install-mysql2-gem)), and [the third question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965876/ruby-on-rails-devise-users-sign-out-not-working) doesn't have any linked questions.

By contrast, [What does ||= (or-equals) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-mean-in-ruby) , which has nine linked questions and is a textbook example of a FAQ, <s>appears on page 4</s>.

**Update:** It's now on the first page (on 50 questions per page), but is still ranking fairly low.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Which sorting type have you selected?

Comment: @genesis-φ: Go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby and click on the "faq" tab.